Websocket callbacks are not called in JavaFX WebView with JRE 8u411
I have a sample JavaFX application with WebView loading HTML from local file. In HTML I'm opening websocket (to wss://echo.websocket.org/) and defining onopen, onmessage and onerror callbacks.
When I run it with 8u401 I see popups, but I don't see anything for 8u411.
I was able to reproduce it on Windows 10 and MacOS.
Java code to reproduce:
package org.example.javafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;

public class WebViewExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example running with " + Runtime.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());

        WebView webView = new WebView();

        webView.getEngine().setOnAlert(arg0 -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Message");
            alert.setHeaderText(arg0.getData());
            alert.show();
        });

        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("main.html");
        webView.getEngine().load(url.toString());

        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

and HTML file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            let socket = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org/");

            socket.onopen = function(e) {
                alert("[open] Connection established");
                socket.send("My name is John");
            };

            socket.onmessage = function(event) {
                alert('[message] Data received from server!');
            };

            socket.onerror = function(event) {
                alert("ERROR!");
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Result on 8u401 - alerts about connection and received messages are visible:

Result on 8u411 - nothing pops up:

Is there anything missing?
I have tried 32bit, 64bit JRE, Mac OS and Windows.

I don't have Java 8 to test this, but on Java 22 (on Mac OSX) it does exactly what I would expect and hangs. If you correct the threading so the JOptionPane.showMessage(...) is executed on the correct thread, it works. And (better) if you replace the JOptionPane with a JavaFX Alert, it also works.

Generally, you should not mix JavaFX and Swing unless you have a very compelling reason to do so, and if you do you have to manage the interaction between the two different UI threads correctly. There seems to be no reason to mix both toolkits here.

@James_D thanks for comments! I have replaced Swing and JOptionPane with JavaFX Alert. Also, I have added screenshots to show expected and actual results on my setup.

The updated version you posted works fine for me on a modern JVM/JavaFX version. As previously mentioned, I don't have an old Java 8 JDK to test with.

This works for me on Windows with JavaFX 22. But unfortunately, I also don't have a way to test this with JavaFX 8 at the moment.

I can confirm the regression in Java 1.8.411; reverting to 1.8.401 restored the expected behavior, as did using JavaFX 21.

Since the issue appears to be confirmed, you may wish to submit a bug report (or go through your LTS support if applicable) if one does not already exist.

Thanks! I have tried to report a bug on linked page, but I'm getting
"Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/submit_start" on this server."

Can you not even reach the page or does the error only occur when you go to submit the issue?

@Slaw I can access linked page and I can fill the form, but after hitting "Submit" button on bottom of the page I get error.
Right now page returns 403 and "This site https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport is experiencing technical difficulty. We are aware of the issue and are working as quick as possible to correct the issue.
We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused. "
I guess I will not report them this bug :)

I was able to report this issue with Oracle Support Portal. They have reproduced it and confirmed that root cause is in JavaFX, and bug was reported here: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8331765
Thanks for your comments!

This appears to be fixed in 8u431.

See also Why did a WebView fail to connect to a WebSocket in JavaFX?
